# Expresion regular para admitir algunas palabras pero rechazar otras

Tags: regex

Necesito una expresión para validar nombres de los usuarios y que no admita palabras como `TEST` `USUARIO` `BASURA` `PRUEBA`:

Pero encontré un usuario con apellido `TOBASURA` por lo que debe validar que si escribo:

> ANDRES TOBASURA -> PERMITIDO
>
> ANDRES BASURA TOBASURA -> ERROR
>
> ANDRES USUARIO TOBASURA -> ERROR
>
> ANDRES TEST TOBASURA -> ERROR

No descarto en un futuro poder detectar y permitir nuevos nombres especiales que encuentre en los usuarios.

Comment: Hola, ¿y qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: ^((?!tobasura).)*$

Esa es la expresión que tengo, al escribir:
Andres tobasura -> regex lo deja pasar
Andres tobasura basura -> regex tiene la palabra que debe escapar y no hace el match

Comment: ¿No crees que una expresión regular para validar que una cadena de texto no contenga 4 palabras definidas, es como matar mosquitos con cañones? Sin entrar en detalles del costo computacional que se requiere para ejecutar un proceso de búsqueda mediante expresiones regulares, si pudieras decir en qué lenguaje deseas implementar tu validación y sobre qué elemento/variable deseas realizarla, seguramente te podremos ayudar con una solución más eficiente que una expresión regular. Saludos

Comment: Claro amigo, no descarto realizarlo por otro medio, no necesariamente por regex, estoy abierto a realizarlo mediante código, el lenguaje es Apex, pero se asemeja a Java.

Answer (score -1):

Entiendo que quieres detectar cuando "BASURA" (por ejemplo) aparece como *palabra aislada* dentro de una cadena dada, pero ignorando el caso en que aparezca dentro de otra palabra como el caso de "TOBASURA". Y lo mismo para el resto de cadenas que indicas.

Para esto las expresiones regulares tienen el carácter especial `\b` que denota un "word **b**oundary", o frontera de palabra. Así la expresión regular `\bBASURA\b` sólo encajará la palabra "BASURA" si delante de ella (y detrás) hay una "frontera de palabra", que es generalmente un espacio o un signo de puntuación. De este modo ya no encajaría con "TOBASURA", pues delante de BASURA aparece una O, que no es una frontera de palabra.

Generalizando esta idea, la expresión regular que buscas es:

```
\b(BASURA|TEST|USUARIO|PRUEBA)\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/aZZzl4/1

Comment: 1Es correcto, hasta ahí la regla funcionaría bien, pero me surge el problema que si de pronto está esta opción:

ANDRES BASURA1 -> me lo permite, pero contiene "basura1" y esto ya no es válido para la calidad de datos.

Comment: Entonces deberías ser más claro a la hora de especificar (no ya mediante expresión regular, sino en lenguaje informal incluso) qué quieres permitir y qué no. ¿Por qué TOBASURA se permite pero BASURA1 no? ¿Es porque contiene una cifra o porque "suena falso"? Lo segundo es difícil de expresar algorítmicamente. ¿GRANBASURA sería válido? ¿Y BASURILLA? Mientras no haya una especificación clara de qué pasa y qué no, es imposible escribir una expresión regular.